# How to configure a request for a MIO route with multiple stops over multiple shifts?

Tags: routes, bing-maps, mio

The scenario I am trying to get MIO to solve is planning a route which leaves from a starting location on day 1, makes a delivery on day 1 then continues on to make another delivery on day 2 at another stop.

In my request there will be many agents departing from the same starting location, bringing deliveries to many stops on different days. The agents do not return to the starting location at the end of their shifts, they either continue on to another delivery or are finished. Some agents will finish their route within one shift, other agents will need multiple shifts to complete their routes.

I dont know what the finishing location of an agent is at the end of its shift. In real life the truck driver will stop somewhere along the way and continue on during their next shift. When the truck driver is done with his/her route they will return to the location of their carrier base, not our starting location where their pickup the deliveries.

I don't know when setting up the request which shifts an agent in particular will need. So I give all agents enough shifts to reach all itinerary items.

How can I configure the MIO request to accomplish this route planning?